# Retrieving XML from a C# function on WCF

Tags: c#

I have a WCF service that I'm using for calling a C# function via URL, this is the code that I use for the url:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "?GetValuesVar={Var}")]

string getHisUmsTimeRedVar(string Var);
```

Once donde that I'm using the parameters of the URL for calling a function and to retrieve a value. My problem is that all the XML code is between `<string></string>` tags.

```
<string>
<?xml version="1.0"?><ArrayOfHistoricVal
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<HistoricVal>
<Date>2016-05-31T22:00:00</Date><Value>2060</Value>
</HistoricVal>
</ArrayOfHistoricVal>
</string>
```

Is there a way to retrieve this values as a normal XML instead of between those two `<string></string>` tags?

Edit: The values to get are in a function like this one:

```
public string getHisUmsTimeRedVar(string idVar)
        {
            try
            {
                ADAMUtil.Log.info("getHisUmsTimeRed. Empieza = ");
                DateTime FechaIni = new DateTime(2015, 05, 05, 0, 0, 0);
                DateTime FechaFin = new DateTime(2018, 05, 05, 0, 0, 0);

                List<HistoricVal> list = new List<HistoricVal>();

                List<His> Historicos = null;
                ADAMUtil.Log.info("getHisUmsTimeRed. Empieza1 = ");
                Historicos = getHisUmsTimeRed("admin", "admin", Convert.ToInt64(idVar), 14, null, 0, 0, FechaIni, FechaFin, 0, "Romance Standard Time");
                ADAMUtil.Log.info("getHisUmsTimeRed. Historicos = " + Historicos.Count);
                for (int i = 0; i < Historicos.Count; i++)
                {
                    HistoricVal item = new HistoricVal();
                    item.Date = Historicos[i].IniDat;
                    item.Value = Historicos[i].Val;
                    list.Add(item);
                }


                String xmlDoc;
                xmlDoc = toXML.VartoXML(list);
                //Browser.BrowserOpen();
                return xmlDoc;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ADAMUtil.Log.info("getHisUmsTimeRed. ex = " + ex.ToString() + ex.StackTrace.ToString());
                return null;
            }
        }
```

And the webinvoke must be an Stream, not a string.

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "?GetValuesVar={Var}")]

stream getHisUmsTimeRedVar(string Var);
```

Comment: Have you tried `XElement getHisUmsTimeRedVar(string Var)`?

Comment: Could you potentially change `getHisUmsTimeRedVar` to return a XmlDocument or XDocument, or do you want to do it once you've received the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your XML string is that it is erroneous XML: the XML declaration should be at the very start. 
You can't easily convert it to a XElement or XDocument like this.

There are thus two solutions:

- Change your method so that it doesn't return a string, but a XElement in the first place.
- Work with your string yourself to remove the additional tags. This solution is not robust to change or edges cases, and I recommend you use the first one. But if you are unable to change the called method, this will at least help you out :

  ```
  //Trims 8 characters (<string>) at the beginning and 9 at the end.
  String correctString = yourString.Substring(8, yourString.Length - 17);
  ```

EDIT: After discussing the issue in the comments, it seemed that only the browser displayed the `<string>` tags, and they were not present in the XML file. This was due to it serializing your string object, most likely.
By either serializing it yourself and passing this to your browser with `XElement.Parse()` or changing the type of your object directly, the browser was able to understand what it was supposed to display.

Comment: I suspect that may not parse though, as I wouldn't expect it to be legal to have `<?xml ...>` within a document. (I haven't tried, admittedly.)

Comment: Nice catch, @DaisyShipton . For some reason, that xml declaration eluded me completely. I'll think of another solution and just delete the answer if I can't. Thank you!

Comment: I actually thought this was the answer, just realized that if I save the xml document it doesn't give me any of the tags, but if I try to open it in a browser it goes between the <String> tags.

Comment: @anion What do you do with your String afterwards? After the trim, it contains exactly what you want. You could parse it in a XElement and save it to XML.

Comment: @Anion Wait, you mean if you just save your original string to a XML document?

Comment: Thing is that I don't want to save it, I want to display it in the browser, but It's having a weird format, what I meant what I talked about saving, was the thing that when saved the XML takes a normal format, but it doesn't when it's displayed on screen.

Comment: When you trim the String as specified in my answer, is the format the one you want to do? If not, try to parse it as soon as you trim it (using something like XElement.Parse(yourString);). Tell me if it answers your problem, I'll update the answer! @Anion

Comment: The trim does not actually work, it cuts the first characters that go between the <string> tags.

Comment: Aaaah, I see! So it's your display that adds the String tags, they are not in the XML in the first place!

Comment: @Anion as soon as you call your method, do XElement.Parse(theresult) and display that XElement, not the string. It should work :)

Comment: Yeap, it worked! Thanks a lot, also I had to change string to stream in the webinvoke.

Comment: @Anion Cool! I'm glad I helped! I'll edit the answer with the additional informations. I'd appreciate if you could select it as Accepted, and edit your question with the additional details so that it may help future users!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public string getHisUmsTimeRedVar
```

To

```
public XDocument getHisUmsTimeRedVar
```

to return proper xml not involved in a string tag.